# R forestplot() function with different coloured text labels

Tags: r, r-forestplot

Is there a way in a forestplot (using the R forestplot() function) to have text labels in different colours on the left hand side of the plot?

i.e. I'd like the plot to look like:
[image]

with different coloured left hand labels. I could plot two forest plots and paste them together, but I'd prefer a solution which would allow all elements to line up correctly on a single plot (there are 9  labels that need to be one colour in one group and ~20 that need to be another in the other group)

If there is, how would I proceed with the forestplot() function and the library to obtain this?

Edit to add a reproducible code snippet:

EDIT: to provide a minimum code example

```
library(forestplot)
library(tidyr)

cohort <- data.frame(Age = c(43, 39, 34, 55, 70, 59, 44, 83, 76, 44, 
                             75, 60, 62, 50, 44, 40, 41, 42, 37, 35, 55, 46), 
                     Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1","2"), class = "factor"))

age.lm <- lm(Age ~ Group, data = cohort)

age.data <- summary(age.lm)$coefficients[2,]

age.data <- rbind(c(0,0,0,1,"Group 1", "n=15"),
                  c(age.data[1], age.data[1]-age.data[2]*1.95, 
                  age.data[1]+age.data[2]*1.95, age.data[4], "Group 2", "n=7"))

colnames(age.data) <- c("mean","lower","upper","p-val","labeltext","numbers")

age.data <- data.frame(age.data)


age.data$mean <- as.numeric(age.data$mean)
age.data$lower <- as.numeric(age.data$lower)
age.data$upper <- as.numeric(age.data$upper)


age.plot <- forestplot(age.data,
           labeltext = c(labeltext,numbers),
           boxsize = 0.1,
           xlog = FALSE,
           clip=c(-20,20),
           xticks=c(-20,-10,0,10,20),
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(ticks=gpar(cex=1)),
           align=c("l","c","l"))
```

This snippet generates a monochrome plot, but I want the labels on the left hand side to be different colours.

EDIT: It initially looks like fpColors() might provide this functionality, but it colours all the text elements in the row with the specified colour, and not just the text label on the left hand side.

Comment: And how is it possible using the forestplot() function and associated library?

Comment: Do not hesitate to share a reproducible example, it will help people to answer and make it appropriate for you to use it one the solution is found

Comment: I've seen @Thomas Lumley on SO before (author of `forestplot()`); perhaps it would be worth contacting him to ask about potential workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `col` argument to modify `text` with [fpColors()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forestplot/versions/3.1.3/topics/fpColors):

```
forestplot(age.data,
           labeltext = c(labeltext,numbers),
           boxsize = 0.1,
           xlog = FALSE,
           clip = c(-20,20),
           xticks = c(-20,-10,0,10,20),
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(ticks=gpar(cex=1)),
           align = c("l","c","l"),
           col = fpColors(text=c('red','blue'))
           )
```

[image]

Comment: I had worked out how to do that, but what if I want just the label "Group x" coloured and not the next column?

Comment: I saw your last Edit. Unfortunately, this seems to be outside parametrization possibilities of the package, and might need recoding of the function.

Comment: I have raised a Github issue on the package page with this feature request, and I've not had a response yet, but I'll upvote this as a partial answer to the issue